# 'KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'wv' / The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0

Tags: python, jupyter, gensim, word-embedding

```
word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
print('Found %s word vectors of word2vec' % len(word2vec.vocab))
```

In the word2vec.vocab it showing error, anyone have any idea to solve it??? i tried word2vec.wc.vocab & word2vec.wc, they doesn't work

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the **full** error message you received?

Answer (score 0):

If you look for the vector of word 'maybe', instead of using word2vec.wv.['maybe'],use word2vec['maybe'].
For more information, Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.
See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4