# KeyedVectors\' object has no attribute \'wv for gensim 4.1.2

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, gensim

i have migrated from gensim 3.8.3 to 4.1.2 and i am using this

`claim = [token for token in claim_text if token in w2v_model.wv.vocab]`

`reference = [token for token in ref_text if token in w2v_model.wv.vocab]`

i am not sure how to replace w2v_model.wv.vocab to newer attribute and i am getting this error

**KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'wv'** can anyone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only use the `.wv` property to fetch the `KeyedVectors` object from another more complete algorithmic model, like a full `Word2Vec` model (which contains a `KeyedVectors` in its `.wv` attribute).

If you're already working with just-the-vectors, there's no need to request the word-vectors subcomponent. Whatever you were going to do, you just do to the `KeyedVectors` directly.

However, you're also using the `.vocab` attribute, which has been replaced. See the migration FAQ for more details:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#4-vocab-dict-became-key_to_index-for-looking-up-a-keys-integer-index-or-get_vecattr-and-set_vecattr-for-other-per-key-attributes

(Mainly: instead of doing an `in w2v_model.wv.vocab`, you may only need to do `in kv_model` or `in kv_model.key_to_index`.)

Answer (score 3):

**KeyedVectors object has no attribute wv**

The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0
If you look for the vector of word 'maybe', instead of using word2vec.wv.['maybe'],use word2vec['maybe']. For more information, Use KeyedVector's .key_to_index dict, .index_to_key list, and methods .get_vecattr(key, attr) and .set_vecattr(key, attr, new_val) instead.

See https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4

```
model.mv.similarity('woman', 'man') #instead of this use Below
model.similarity('woman', 'man')
```

Ref : ['KeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'wv' / The vocab attribute was removed from KeyedVector in Gensim 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68234684/)